# How to open IE with specific user name and password, even though its not prompting for credentials using selenium Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to open IE with specific user name and password, even though its not prompting for credentials using selenium Java ?

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer(); 
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);

driver.get("https://uyiuyiuysdf.org");

Comment: How I open IE with different user manully like - hold the mouse on IE and press Shift with Right click on IE, we see the option as run as different user and same needed using selenium webdriver

Comment: To run IE as another user you have to specify the user's profile location (local vs domain). See this http://techtips.tv/windows/how-to-run-internet-explorer-as-a-different-user/. But I doubt you would be able to pass the credentials prompt.